# Keeping SSIS packages under the source control

Tags: version-control, ssis

I store all SSIS packages in Subversion repository, their configuration files as well. Configuration file almost always stored in the same folder where package is.

Problem is - SSIS seems to always store path to configuration file (the one saved in the package itself) as an absolute path.

When someone else checks out folder with the package in the location different from where I had on my development PC the configuration file is not detected (because my absolute path is stored and it doesn't exist on the other developer PC). So another developer has to remove this configuration and add it again from where it is now on his local hard drive. Then changed package is saved which will cause new version to be committed. When I get that version from SVN it will no longer match local path on my PC.

On a related note: another developer may want to change values in configuration file as well. If I later get the latest version of everything from SVN package will no longer work on my PC.

How do you work around these inconveniences?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to save your configuration in a database with an environment variable as the first configuration to tell it what database to look in, that's what we do. We have scripts to populate ssisconfig for each server in our source control, but the package uses the actual table data for the database in the environment variable we are using.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who has heard my SQL Saturday presentations knows I don't much care for XML and this is one of the reasons. A trick to using XML configuration with varying locations is to use an environment variable (indirect configuration) to direct SSIS where it can look for that resource. The big, big downside to this approach is you'd generally need to create an environment variable for each set of configuration files or have a massive, honking .dtsconfig file which becomes painful for versioning.

The option I prefer if XML configuration is a must is that the "variableness" is removed. Developers and admins get together and everyone agrees "there will be a folder everywhere SSIS is done to hold configuration files and that location is X" and then it's just a matter of solving for X. At a previous job, we used D:\ssisdata\configs

@HLGEM's approach of a table for configurations is hands down my favorite approach to SSIS configuration (until you get to 2012 and their project deployment model where configuration is an entirely different animal)

Answer (score 1):

I add a folder called "config" under my projects folder, add it to source control and mantain the config file in this folder. You can also add it to the SSIS project if you like.

I think its a good solution because everybody can have this folder and dowload the config file.

When the package is deployed it will read the config file from where you inform in the deployment manifest so this solution wont impact your development

Comment: I mentioned in my OP - I already store configuration file in SVN. Having it in subfolder doesn't solve any of the problem I mentioned.

Comment: humm, dont you all have a standard folder to store your projects?